# Selenium getText() returns empty string

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Just started studying Selenium. I have a problem. Сan't get text. getText() returns empty string. getAttribute() returns null.

The getText() is used on a HTML element that looks like this:
first element:

```
<span _ngcontent-enu-c116="" class="line-chart-tab-value ng-star-inserted"> 2 807,60 $ </span>
```

second element:

```
<span _ngcontent-enu-c116="" class="line-chart-tab-value ng-star-inserted"> 200,00 $ </span>
```

find by xpath:

```
WebElement sale = (By.xpath("//label[1]//span[@class='line-chart-tab-value ng-star-inserted']")));
System.out.println("Sale=" + sale.getText());
WebElement saleReturn= driver.findElement((By.xpath("//label[2]//span[@class='line-chart-tab-value ng-star-inserted']")));
System.out.println("Return=" + saleReturn.getText());
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Are you selecting the elements (are you getting the correct path to the element)? If you do `.getAttribute("outerHTML")` do you find the element that you are looking for? Second you are missing `driver.findElement` for your `sale` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> Ele =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='line-chart-tab-value ng-star-inserted']"));
        for(int i=0;i<Ele.size();i++) {
            System.out.println("Sale "+Ele.get(0).getText());
            System.out.println("Return "+Ele.get(1).getText());
        }
```

Comment: Thanks,it turned out there was simply not enough time to get the values
added wait and it worked